# Bidirectional one-to-many associations with indexed collections in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

Last summer, I asked a question regarding [how to add new object to an IList mapped as a one-to-many with NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253490/how-to-add-new-object-to-an-ilist-mapped-as-a-one-to-many-with-nhibernate). One of the answers let me to this paragraph in the [documentation](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-bidirectional):

> Please note that NHibernate does not support bidirectional one-to-many associations with an indexed collection (list, map or array) as the "many" end, you have to use a set or bag mapping.

While I am pretty sure I understand *what* this paragraph says, I have no idea *why* or *how* to work around this limitation. As I am now again working with a model that seems to require a "bidirectional one-to-many association with an index collection", I figured the time was right for follow-up questions:

1. Why does NHibernate have this limitation on associations? It is my impression that the guys behind NHibernate are quite clever, so I assume there is a pretty good reason.
2. What are the common workarounds for this shortcoming? Making the collection a non-indexed bag and adding an explicit `Position` property to the child class? Any better solutions?

Answer (score 5):

This was asked 4 months ago, so I don't know if you're still interested :-)

The conceptual reason for not supporting bidirectional indexed associations is simple: the index only makes sense in one direction.

For example, consider an `Invoice` class with a `Lines` property of type `IList<Line>`.

Setting `line.Invoice = anInvoice` makes no sense, as it's impossible to determine what the list index should be.

Keep in mind that NHibernate "sees" bidirectional relationships as two different relationships (hence the need for `inverse="true"` on the side not in charge of maintaining it)

The workaround is exactly what you suggested: a Position/Index/etc property in the child class.